# Which is the better of the django event apps?

Tags: django, calendar, scheduling

I've been looking at [django-swingtime](http://code.google.com/p/django-swingtime/), [django-schedule](http://thauber.com/blog/post/django-schedule/) and [django-agenda](http://github.com/dokterbob/django-agenda).

Any recommendations of which is them easier to use, and if so any practical code examples out there? Couldn't find useful documentation or examples in the respective projects.

My requirement is to have a number of events and track their occurrences, but the events are custom things, for example, a project management system where a regular amount of time is spent on each project where an event is a task and the occurrences are the hours spent regularly on each task.

Comment: Let me update the description to be more precise.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if you already checked django-packages but it has a small grid about these: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/calendar/

Answer (score 3):

if your requirement is just to display the calendar on certain data which you have in database then i recommend the use of inbuilt HTMLcalendar in python2.5 which is easy to use.

More details you can find at
http://journal.uggedal.com/creating-a-flexible-monthly-calendar-in-django

Comment: Nope, this is not what I'm looking for. I've added more details to the question to explain what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Maccesch 's answer and having in mind that I'm a total beginner to Django I could only get Django Happenings to work: https://github.com/wreckage/django-happenings  I hope this project will continue to exist.